# Is there a Groovy XML parser that doesn't ignore the comment node?

Tags: xml, groovy, parsing

I'm using the XmlParser to insert nodes into an existing XML.  Unfortunately this parser ignores the comment nodes which I would like to keep in place.  Is there another parser I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690526/preserve-formatting-when-updating-xml-file-with-groovy#answer-20720694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [StreamingMarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy's+StreamingMarkupBuilder). You can extract comments but not CDATA.