# preserve formatting when updating xml file with groovy

Tags: xml, regex, groovy

I have a large number of XML files that contain URLs.  I'm writing a groovy utility to find each URL and replace it with an updated version.

Given example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
    <content>
        <section>
            <link>
                <url>/some/old/url</url>
            </link>
            <link>
                <url>/some/old/url</url>
            </link>
        </section>
        <section>
            <link>
                <url>
                    /a/different/old/url?with=specialChars&amp;escaped=true
                </url>
            </link>
        </section>
    </content>
</page>
```

Once the script has run, example.xml should contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
    <content>
        <section>
            <link>
                <url>/a/new/and/improved/url</url>
            </link>
            <link>
                <url>/a/new/and/improved/url</url>
            </link>
        </section>
        <section>
            <link>
                <url>
                    /a/different/new/and/improved/url?with=specialChars&amp;stillEscaped=true
                </url>
            </link>
        </section>
    </content>
</page>
```

This is easy to do using groovy's excellent xml support, except that I want to **change the URLs and nothing else** about the file.

By that I mean:

- whitespace must not change (files might contain spaces, tabs, or both)
- comments must be preserved
- windows vs. unix-style line separators must be preserved
- the xml declaration at the top must not be added or removed
- attributes in tags must retain their order

So far, after trying many combinations of XmlParser, DOMBuilder, XmlNodePrinter, XmlUtil.serialize(), and so on, I've landed on reading each file line-by-line and applying an ugly hybrid of the xml utilities and regular expressions.

Reading and writing each file:

```
files.each { File file ->
    def lineEnding = file.text.contains('\r\n') ? '\r\n' : '\n'
    def newLineAtEof = file.text.endsWith(lineEnding)
    def lines = file.readLines()
    file.withWriter { w ->
        lines.eachWithIndex { line, index ->
            line = update(line)
            w.write(line)
            if (index < lines.size-1) w.write(lineEnding)
            else if (newLineAtEof) w.write(lineEnding)
        }
    }
}
```

Searching for and updating URLs within a line:

```
def matcher = (line =~ urlTagRegexp) //matches a <url> element and its contents
matcher.each { groups ->
    def urlNode = new XmlParser().parseText(line)
    def url = urlNode.text()
    def newUrl = translate(url)
    if (newUrl) {
        urlNode.value = newUrl
        def replacement = nodeToString(urlNode)
        line = matcher.replaceAll(replacement)
    }
}

def nodeToString(node) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    writer.withPrintWriter { printWriter ->
        def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(printWriter)
        printer.preserveWhitespace = true
        printer.print(node)
    }
    writer.toString().replaceAll(/[\r\n]/, '')
}
```

This mostly works, except it can't handle a  tag split over multiple lines, and messing with newlines when writing the files back out is cumbersome.

I'm new to groovy, but I feel like there must be a groovier way of doing this.

Comment: It's not Groovy related issue but more general one. If you want to parse XML and write it back again I see no way to preserve formatting, whitespaces and everything (unless there is some special lib for that). You can either don't parse and just replace URLs itself with a shifty regexp (full file scan) or parse and build XML again while setting desired formatting (desired but altered).

Comment: IT IS Groovy related issue. More particularly, it relates to Groovy JDK. The question should be interpreted as such: "is there a class in Groovy JDK, that allows easy reading of XML files WITHOUT losing comments, whitespaces, etc.?"
If so, the answer is: "no". XmlSlurper ignores lot of things, I stumbled on it myself.
Solution would be to use non-groovy classes for that. If files are not big (say, under 50 MB), it is reasonable (and, probably, easiest) to load them with JDOM2 class SAXBuilder. The result is DOM-tree, which you can: 
1. iterate and search via XPath
2. modify
3. save to file.

Comment: @topr yes, I suppose my question boils down to "is there some special lib for that?"

Comment: @akhikhl SAXBuilder looks promising. I'd accept that as an answer if you made one.

Comment: Yes, I use SAXBuilder for such transformations. Below is the reference to the example and some notes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just created gist at: https://gist.github.com/akhikhl/8070808 to demonstrate how such transformation is done with Groovy and JDOM2.

Important notes:

1. Groovy technically allows using any java libraries. If something
   cannot be done with Groovy JDK, it can be done with other library.
2. jaxen library (implementing XPath) should be included explicitly (via @Grab or via maven/gradle), since it's an optional dependency of JDOM2.
3. The sequence of @Grab/@GrabExclude instructions fixes the quirky dependence of jaxen on JDOM-1.0.
4. XPathFactory.compile also supports variable binding and filters (see online javadoc).
5. XPathExpression (which is returned by compile) supports two major functions - evaluate and evaluateFirst. evaluate always returns a list of all XML-nodes, satisfying the specified predicate, while evaluateFirst returns just the first matching XML-node.

**Update**

The following code:

```
new XMLOutputter().with {
  format = Format.getRawFormat()
  format.setLineSeparator(LineSeparator.NONE)
  output(doc, System.out)
}
```

solves a problem with preserving whitespaces and line separators. getRawFormat constructs a format object that preserves whitespaces. LineSeparator.NONE instructs format object, that it should not convert line separators.

The gist mentioned above contains this new code as well.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!  Also, how did I go this long without knowing about @Grab?!

Comment: After trying it with more varied input, I have to qualify my praise a little -- some things are moved around and line endings are changed to the platform default.  But it's still much simpler and more robust than anything I had done.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code that solves a problem with preserving whitespaces and line separators.

Comment: I don't think JDOM preserves the order of XML attributes, which is probably why things move around.

Comment: This worked for me thank you! also if only one node is required use the evaluateFirst(doc) method

Answer (score 9):

There is a solution without any 3rd party library.

```groovy
def xml = file.text
def document = groovy.xml.DOMBuilder.parse(new StringReader(xml))
def root = document.documentElement
use(groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory) {
    // manipulate the XML here, i.e. root.someElement?.each { it.value = 'new value'}
}

def result = groovy.xml.dom.DOMUtil.serialize(root)

file.withWriter { w ->
    w.write(result)
}
```

Taken from http://jonathan-whywecanthavenicethings.blogspot.de/2011/07/keep-your-hands-off-of-my-whitespace.html